# Is there a callback function concept in Java to do async I/O as it is in Javascript?

Tags: java

I am a Javascript front-end developer, but need to write a simple Java program to write file and sent Email and HTTP request.

Here is the Java code that I use to write log to disk file:

```
    @Override
public void log(String text) {
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    DateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String logDateString = sdf.format(date);
    //System.out.println("logDateString: " + logDateString);
    BufferedWriter bwToUse = null;
    if(logDateString.compareTo(m_firstOpenDate) == 0) {
        // use old buffer writer
        bwToUse = this.m_bw;
    } else {
        // generate new buffer writer
        // update m_firstOpenDate
        m_firstOpenDate = logDateString;


        try {
            // close previous day log
            this.m_bw.close();
            this.m_fw = new FileWriter(m_path + logDateString + ".log", true);
            this.m_bw = new BufferedWriter(this.m_fw);
            bwToUse = this.m_bw;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        bwToUse.write(sdf1.format(date) + ": " + text + "\n");
        bwToUse.flush();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can ignore the detail.

My real question is that for those heavy IO operation, e.g.: file reading, sending email and making HTTP request(post data to a web hook), how to do it in a non-blocking async way in Java? I know it is standard in Javascript to use callback, but in Java, how do you do async http request?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the socket itself need to block? That's usually the case, and it's typical in Java just to do that kind of I/O synchronously, since you're not blocking some UI thread.

Comment: yes, just use multi-threads in java. if someone *has to* do async, google async libraries. see my profile for one:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest concept in Java is [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

But you should be aware that Java has a multithreading concurrency model, as opposed to single-threaded JavaScript with asynchronous concurrency model. If you're new to this concept, then you better start with a [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Also for IO-operations you should consider [non-blocking IO API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)).

Comment: General concurrency model explanation +1

Comment: @sergey,  The java.nio.file doc that you provided in the 2nd link doesn't say it is non-blocking. Is this correct? If java API provides non-blocking I/O, it will be great, since I can avoid the concurrency code.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu This third (not second) link is indeed misleading. The NIO2 feature (introduced in Java 7) with the `java.nio.file` package is part of the [Non-blocking I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_(Java)) feature (which was introduced in Java 1.4). There are several tutorials about it, for example the [Java NIO Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html).

Comment: Sergy: Consider an update to your explanation and changing the link(s).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose thanks, your link is indeed better. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @SergeyPetunin Yours was not wrong but pointed only to the file API, and I think you wanted to point the whole. Nevertheless, your answer is a great one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FutureTask](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).  You should implemets `Callable` interface. Here is a [sample](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/java-futuretask-example-program.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use new Thread for this, which won't block the main thread
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html
Thread means you can do multiple things in one time (simply told)
You can call the function as follows:

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        log(SOME_TEXT);
    }
}.start();
```

But make sure SOME_TEXT won't change when the thread is running
And make sure the log ends in some time, if it won't, you can log multiple times and there will be many Threads which can make trouble.
To learn something more about it, use @SergeyPetunin 's answer.

Comment: thanks! This kind of Thread() looks very doable in my simple program.